# Find expected rate of return without drift based on ito process

Tags: brownian-motion, expected-return, binary-options, payoff

[image: Find the expected rate of return of stock based on Ito Process]

I would like to know how to solve question (ii), I know it is a cash-or-nothing option but I have no idea how to get the expected rate of return even I use put-call parity. Could anybody guide me I would very appreciate it.